# How to get Template.dynamic to work

Tags: javascript, meteor

I tried ,but i cant get it to work! i changed the value of Template in many ways, but still not working.

In html >>

```
<body>

    {{> Template.dynamic template=Template data=data}}

</body>
```

In Meteor.isClient >>

```
  Template.body.helpers({
    'Template': function() {
      return page.template;
    },
    'data': function() {
      return page.getTemplate();
    }
  });
```

I'm using the last version,  1.1.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few suggestions:

1. Make sure `page.template` is a **string**. It should be the **name** of the template and not a template instance.
2. Make sure `page.getTemplate()` is a simple object - this should be a template context and not a template instance.
3. It may be that the name `Template` for your helper causes some kind of conflict. Try `templateName` or something more descriptive.

Comment: 'page.getTemplate => return page.template' will return a simple string, i was testing it to understand why it wont work, and page.template is working fine but when i changed the value of page.template nothing will happen, i gave it a function instead of string but still nothing.

Comment: I will add a question for it

Answer (score 1):

You asked that in another thread as well and I made a MeteorPad for that:

http://meteorpad.com/pad/oPhK4KqjiSztRSa9K/SimpleDynamicTemplateSwitch

Cheers,
Tom

Ref to the similar thread: [How to force Template.dynamic to re render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31051764/how-to-force-template-dynamic-to-re-render/31053297#31053271)

Comment: In this one i just wanted to make sure the way i'm suing is correct its a different question, but related, thanks again