# How to force Template.dynamic to re render

Tags: javascript, meteor

I read and tried a lots of solution but i wasn't able to force the Template.dynamic to render again.

In html >>

```
<body>
    {{> Template.dynamic template=Template}}
</body>
```

In Meteor.isClient >>

```
Template.body.helpers({
    'Template': function() {
      return page.template;
    }
  });
```

I have a function on `hashchange` `event` which will change the `value` of `page.template`, the `event` works fine and value will changed every time, but i can't force the `Template.dynamic` to render again.

`page.template` is string

I have a function `page.getTemplate() > return page.template` just to try all options

I'm using the last version of Meteor  `1.1.0.2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure how your app is organized but this should be an easy task. Just use a ReactiveVar to save your active template-name you wish to have selected.

I made a simple MeteorPad for you. Hopefully this is what you are looking for.

http://meteorpad.com/pad/oPhK4KqjiSztRSa9K/SimpleDynamicTemplateSwitch

Cheers
Tom

Comment: Can you make an example for changing the template by global var not template events

Comment: In this case you should use just a global Session var or a global Reactive var. Template {{ > Template.dynamic }} needs some kind of reactive element to recognize that something should be changed. Therefor you can use SessionVar or ReactiveVar as the suggested method. Is this ok for you?

Answer (score 2):

Before start , i changed some objects , `page.template` is now object and `page.template.get()` will return string, but i don't use it, i pass the `template name` in `Sessions`, and this is my `page.template.set()`

```
page.template.set = function(name) {
    Session.set('template', name);
  };
```

Well i found the answer, you need to set a dependency to Sessions, i have done this so far

```
Template.body.helpers({
    'Template': function() {
      return Session.get('template');
    }
  });
```

> Edited
>   Because of client hack i decided to changed something (you can change the session in console, and i want my router decide to which template should be shown)

```
page.template.set = function(name) {
  page.template.name = name;
  Session.set('template', name);
};
page.template.get = function() {
  return page.template.name;
};

Template.body.helpers({
  'Template': function() {
     return Session.get('template') ? page.template.get() : page.template.get();
  }
});
```

Comment: Oops we finally edited nearly same time ;-) If possible you should try to use ReactiveVars as template vars. Session vars are global reactive vars and not nessecary here.

Comment: What do you mean by "client hack"? Everything inside the Javascript client is accessibel and could be "hacked" by known users. If you want to secure your app, you have to do this on server side. - Your addon code is now just using the "Reactive Behavior" from Session vars. If you want to control this by yourself, you can have a look for template based or global Trackers. Checkout in meteor documentation.